# How to open a new page when button is clicked on

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web-applications

The question is vague so allow me to clarify. I am developing a web app locally on eclipse and using Servlets, JSP, and an html document to design a web page.

I have a home page which has two buttons, signup and login. I have one file, called index.jsp, which has the html configurations of the homescreen.

So, when signup is clicked on, how can I get the server to load a new page with text input boxes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the request from one jsp to another. Lets say after the index.jsp you want to go to login.jsp when the button is pressed.Then create a form like this:

```
<form action="login.jsp">
<input name="username" type="text"><br>
<input name="password" type="password">
<input type="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Now in the login.jsp you can get the username and password using

```
String username=request.getParameter("username");
String password=request.getParameter("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window/tab use a blank target:

```
<a href="SIGNUP_PAGE" target="_blank">Sign Up</a>
```

Comment: Alright thanks, now how do I capture and store his first and last name?